# How to change the websocket port for the Selenium VNC?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I'm running the Selenium on Kubernetes, behind the Ingress-Nginx controller.

One thing I noticed is when I try to see the live VNC through the Selenium Grid web, the browser keeps trying to connect the `4444` port of the Selenium grid server for the WebSocket connection.

Is there a way to make it point the `80` port instead?

I already tried to switch the port number for the Selenium router to 80 (`SE_ROUTER_PORT to 80`), but apparently, the WebSocket is still not working.

This is what I'm seeing on the browser console:

[image]

- I already confirmed the functionality itself with the `kube-proxy` localhost proxying.

Thank you very much.